# Integrating Mollie payments in NestJS backend

Tags: module, nestjs, mollie

I am trying to integrate Mollie payments into my NestJS backend.

To make a connection with Mollie, I have to use their MollieClient function. However, when I try to use it in a service I get the error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the NewUserService (UserService, MailService, ConfigService, JwtService, ?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [4] is available in the NewUserModule context.
```

I am pretty sure this means I have to add a Mollie module/service to the NewUserModule, but I think the package doesn't actually come with a module made for NestJS. So if I try to make a Mollie module/service or use the MollieClient in another service, it asks me to provide it whilst I don't have anything to provide.

I'm pretty new to NestJS and backend development in general, so am I mistaken? Or is there a module added in the installed package?
If there isn't a module, should I make one? What exactly should be in such a module? Is there some sort of guide for it?

I realise this might be a rather vague series of questions, but I'm not very sure how to approach this.

Edit:
Rewrote the question for clarification.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The message means, that Nest does not now how to resolve the 5th constructor argument of your `NewUserService`. I assume this is something like a `MollieService`?

You need to add `MollieService` as `Provider` to your `NewUserModule`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [...],
  controllers: [...],
  providers: [
    ...otherProviders,
    MollieService
  ]
})
export class NewUserModule {}
```

Or you can create a separate `MollieModule` and import it in `NewUserModule`:

```
@Module({
  providers: [ MollieService ],
  exports: [ MollieService ] // export MollieService, so that other modules can use it
})
export class MollieModule {}
```

```
@Module({
  imports: [MollieModule],
  controllers: [...],
  providers: [...] // no need to provide MollieService here, because it's imported from MollieModule
})
export class NewUserModule {}
```

Of course you must also implement the `MollieService` using their SDK.

A recommend to read the [Documentation on Modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/modules). They are a little hard to understand at a first sight, but a powerful concept!

**EDIT:**
I would suggest to wrap the MollySDK in a service. This way you're not dealing with molly at various places in your app and prevent leaking it's api and types into your services.

```
@Injectable()
export class MollyService {
  private readonly mollyClient: WhateverType;

  constructor() {
    this.mollyClient = createMollieClient({ apiKey: 'test_dHar4XY7LxsDOtmnkVtjNVWXLSlXsM' });
  }

  createPayment() {
    this.mollieClient.payments.create({...});
  }
}
```

This service could be injected as usual.

However if you really want to use the molly-client directly, you have to use a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#custom-providers-1)

```
@Module({
  providers: [{
    provides: 'MOLLY_CLIENT',
    useFactory: () => createMollieClient({ apiKey: 'test_dHar4XY7LxsDOtmnkVtjNVWXLSlXsM' }) // you could also use useValue instead of useFactory
  }],
  exports: [ 'MOLLY_CLIENT' ]
})
export class MollieModule {}
```

Then inject it into `NewUsersService` like so:

```
constructor(@Inject('MOLLY_CLIENT')private readonly mollyClient: WhateverType) {}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

The thing is that I don't have something like a MollieService. The only thing I know from the Mollie docs is that you use their MollieClient to start a connection. However, to use this client I have to add it to the module. But if I make a Service to add, it always asks me to provide the MollieClient in some kind of module, but I'm not sure how.

I wasn't clear on this, so I'll add it to the original question.

Comment: @RutgerCappendijk I updated my answer. Next time you should add the actually failing code.